# Visual Studio Code: Creating an Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension for vs code and want to know if it's possible to add a tab to this bottom pane:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't look like the API supports adding a new tab to that panel, but you can create and write to a custom Output Channel, by using this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#OutputChannel