# VSCode extension for panel

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am new to VSCode and was wondering if it is possible to create additional tabs in the panel (With an Extension or just with VSCode). For example an interaktive Python window like in VS2019.

[image: Space for the additional tab]

I haven't found anything on this topic, whether it is possible or not, so maybe you know if it is possible ( or planned for the future).

Comment: This has been asked before, I'm pretty sure this isn't possible at the moment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564607/visual-studio-code-creating-an-extension/53651178#53651178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same question that @Gama11 linked, but unfortunately it has not been answered so I can't mark it as duplicated. Right now it is not possible, but the [January 2020 changes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_42) shows the experimental *"Moving views from the Sidebar to the Panel"*. Even though *This is only a preview of the features and many aspects of it are likely to change including the limitations mentioned above.* it still gives me hope that this might be possible at some point.